# String.Format() - Repassing params but adding more parameters

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting, params-keyword

I would like to do something like that:

```
public string GetMessage(params object otherValues[]) {
    return String.Format(this.Message, this.FirstValue, otherValues);
}
```

So, I would like to repass an array of params to `String.Format()` but adding a new parameter.

What would be the best way to do that, knowing that we could "rebuild" a new array of objects and this doesn't seems good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues)
{
    return String.Format(this.Message, new[] { this.FirstValue }.Concat(otherValues).ToArray<object>());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly the `ToArray()` builds a new structure.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension methods:

```
public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues) 
{
    var values = new[] { this.FirstName }.Concat(otherValues).ToArray();
    return String.Format(this.Message, values);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking at :-) It won't. Adding it. Thanks.

Comment: Will that put `this.FirstName` before the first element of  `otherValues` like the OP had in their question?

Answer (score 1):

In case there are often few `other` parameters, I would use the existing overloads:

```
public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues) {
    if (otherValues == null) return string.Format(this.Message, this.FirstValue);

    switch (otherValues.Length)
    {
        case 0:
            return string.Format(this.Message, this.FirstValue);
        case 1:
            return string.Format(this.Message, this.FirstValue, otherValues[0]);
        case 2:
            return string.Format(this.Message, this.FirstValue, otherValues[0], otherValues[1]);
        default:
            return string.Format(this.Message, new[] { this.FirstValue }.Concat(otherValues).ToArray()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Preprocess Message

If you don't want a creation of a new array in every *GetMessage(...)* call you can **insert *FirstValue*** into *Message* at the beginning **once a time**. And then *GetMessage(...)* just uses the *otherValues* parameter for *string.Format(...)*.

The *Message* property is initialized once after *FirstValue* is set, e.g. in constructor or in an init method like so:

```
void InitMessage()
{
    Message = String.Format(Message, FirstValue, "{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}");
}
```

The *InitMessage* method initializes first index in *Message* with *FirstValue* and the rest of indexes with "{index}", i.e. "{0}", "{1}", "{2}",... (It is allowed to have more `params` elements than message indexes).

Now *GetMessage* can call *String.Format* without any array operations like so:

```
public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues)
{
  return String.Format(Message, otherValues);
}
```

### Example:

Assume following property values:
`this.Message = "First value is '{0}'. Other values are '{1}' and '{2}'."` and `this.FirstValue = "blue"`.

*InitMessage* changes *Message* to:
`"First value is 'blue'. Other values are '{0}' and '{1}'."`.

*GetMessage* call
`GetMessage("green", "red")`

results in
`"First value is 'blue'. Other values are 'green' and 'red'."`.

Comment: @brernder: Interesting approach. Can be useful in others problems. But as you are using Concat(), it seems to be more work, as a direct use of Concat() in Format should solve it, too.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer by just adding "{...}" parameters to *String.Format* call in *InitMessage* method.

Answer (score 0):

Another messy way is to hack your way around the formatting using RegEx if you really can't create another structure for the array.

```
private string FormatEval(Match m)
{
    int val = -1;
    string formatted = m.Value;
    if (int.TryParse(m.Groups["index"].Value, out val))
        formatted = val == 0 ? this.FirstValue : "{" + (val - 1).ToString() + "}";
    return formatted;
}

public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues)
{
    string format = Regex.Replace(this.Message, @"\{(?<index>\d+)\}", FormatEval);
    return string.Format(format, otherValues);
}
```

Basically just parse the format string for the formatting tokens ({0}, {1}) etc. 
And decrement their index. If the token is {0} originally, replace it with the this.FirstName string.

Essentially what this is doing is performing the first step of String.Format manually, and then passing the resulting string to the REAL String.Format method to finish off.

Answer (score 0):

## Pass discrete elements

To avoid array creation in everey *GetMessage* call you could pass *otherValues* by its discrete elements:

```
public string GetMessage(params object[] otherValues)
{
  return String.Format(Message,
                       FirstValue,
                       GetOrDefault(otherValues, 0),
                       GetOrDefault(otherValues, 1),
                       GetOrDefault(otherValues, 2),
                       GetOrDefault(otherValues, 3),
                       GetOrDefault(otherValues, 4));
}

private object GetOrDefault(object[] otherValues, int index)
{
  if (otherValues == null)
    return null;

  if (index < otherValues.Length)
    return otherValues[index];

  return null;
}
```